# PHP sending mail

Tags: php

On my server I am trying to send an email via PHP but it always just says message not set, even after hardcoding in values and removing the header it still says message not sent. What could the problem be?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


$recipient = $_POST["recipient"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$body =  $_POST["body"];
$headers = 'From: admin@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: admin@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$sendMail = mail($recipient, $title, $body, $headers);

if( $sendMail == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }

?>
```

Comment: you also have a PHP error?

Comment: myserver = local server?

Comment: What's the server environment?  Windows?  Linux?  Is PHP mail properly configured?

Answer (score 1):

I dont see problem with the code. Mostly because your mail server is not configured .